# "Ignored Tags preferences" link under "Featured questions" is broken

Tags: bug, ignored-tags

- Go to [Featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab;
- Scroll to the bottom of the list of questions;
- Follow the link in the comment "Hiding questions because of your [Ignored Tags preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1068099) for tags:"

**Actual result:** a new page opened with the following message:

```
Page Not Found

We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.

Try searching for similar questions

Browse our recent questions

Browse our popular tags

If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.
```

**Expected result:** A configuration page opened.

**Notes**

- I could not reproduce the problem for the second time, because the message with the broken link disappeared when I refreshed the page;
- I never set any ignored tags in my preferences;
- The broken link seems to have a wrong user id (not mine).